# Can version-script provide only versioned symbols without defaults?

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, ld

I know I can use a version script when linking my shared library, e.g.

```
some_version { global: foo; };
```

When linking against this library specifically, the other objects will link against `foo@@some_version` therefore preventing versioning issues.

However if some object was linked against an older version of the same library which didn't use versioning, it will link against just `foo`, which my new library will still satisfy. I don't want that. My library broke foo's ABI. I want ldd to choose old symbols from the old library for old code.

So is there a way to make my library provide `foo@@some_version` (or `foo@some_version`) but not plain `foo`?